# IE: Placeholder of input field affect the width of select box

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, placeholder, dropdown

```
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="some text">
 <select>
  <option>op1</option>
  <option>op2</option>
  <option>op3</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

The first I click on select box. It's work, width of select area fit to select control.
But If I click on text field then click to select box, the select area look larger.
If I remove placeholder attribute for input field, it work properly.
I think this is the issue of internet explorer placeholder.
https://jsfiddle.net/22v1og48/
Any ideas for this issue? How to still keep placeholder but select box still work properly?

Comment: Gotta love microsoft! :(

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix this issue was to remove the placeholder on focus and set it back on blur:

```js
$('#a1')
  .data('placeholder', $('#a1').attr('placeholder'))
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="a1" type="text" placeholder="some text"><select>
    <option>op1</option>
    <option>op2</option>
    <option>op3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

> Note that in IE the `placeholder` disappear when you focus, but this is no how it works in other browsers (firefox/chrome), where the placeholder disappear when you start typing. This code will change this behavior, but will make the `select` keep it's original size.

Also note that I used jQuery for the example, but you can do exactly the same without jQuery (it's was only faster to write this example, thats all).